# Applying one equation into values of multiple variables (Stata)

Tags: stata

I have several variables expressed differently with the following values as an example.

I want to multiply all values where the value is expressed as a ratio/proportion (e.g. unemployment_inc) by 100.

```
unemployment_inc   lfp_gender       unemployment_gender     lfp_inc
.2335658           17.35                  83.6            .3786077
.2335658           17.35                  83.6            .3786077
.2335658           17.35                  83.6            .3786077
```

I want the data to eventually look as follows:

```
unemployment_inc   lfp_gender       unemployment_gender     lfp_inc
 23.3              17.35                  83.6                37.8
 23.3          17.35                      83.6                    37.8
 23.3          17.35
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
local vars_proportion unemployment_inc lfp_inc
foreach var of varlist `vars_proportion' {
    replace `var' = `var' * 100
}
```